# .Replace works in powershell but not batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

My batch script looks like this:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Replacing instances of type="module" in index.html with type="text/javascript"
cd www

(Get-Content index.html).Replace("module", "javascript") | Set-Content index.html
```

When I try to use .Replace in powershell, it works fine, but run from a batch script it fails with the error `.Replace("module" was unexpected at this time.`

```
(Get-Content index.html) -replace 'module', 'javascript' | Set-Content index.html
```

also came up with same error. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's because batch/cmd is not PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to call powershell from a .bat script, here's a way.  The output file would have to be different from the input file.  The "> index2.html" part is run by cmd, so it's encoded in ascii, not unicode.

```
type index.html | powershell $input -replace 'module','javascript' > index2.html
```

Or to keep it completely within powershell.  The file encoding would be "ansi".

```
powershell "(get-content index.html) -replace 'module','javascript' | set-content index.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot expect `cmd.exe` to run `powershell.exe` commands without telling [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) to use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for them, here's an answer based upon that:

```bat
@If Not Exist "www\index.html" (GoTo :EOF)Else CD "www"
@Echo(
@Echo Replacing instances of 'type="module"' in index.html with 'type="text/javascript"'.
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path 'index.html') -Replace 'type=\"module\"', 'type=\"text/javascript\"' | Set-Content -Path 'index.html'"
```

The [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) command line itself could also be shortened a little, *if necessary*:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GC 'index.html') -Replace 'type=\"module\"','type=\"text/javascript\"'|SC 'index.html'"
```

The above example assumes that the location of your installed PowerShell executable is the current directory, or one of those listed under `%PATH%`, and if not in the current directory, there is no extensionless file named `powershell` in the current directory or one with an extension listed under `%PATHEXT%`.

If you wanted to use the `.Replace` syntax, which requires at least [powershell-3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-3.0) it is effectively the same method:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GC 'index.html').Replace('type=\"module\"','type=\"text/javascript\"')|SC 'index.html'"
```

However, if you're using [powershell-3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-3.0)+, you may find that it's more efficient using the `-Raw` option with `Get-Content`:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GC 'index.html' -Raw).Replace('type=\"module\"','type=\"text/javascript\"')|SC 'index.html'"
```

The answers above are performing a search for the string, `type="module"` and replacing it with `type="text/javascript"`. If you wish to use something less robust/more simple, like replacing `module` with `javascript`, then use `-Replace 'module','javascript'`, or `.Replace('module','javascript')` instead.

Should you be aware that your [html](/questions/tagged/html) file is, for instance, UTF-8 encoded, you could maintain that encoding by stipulating it as further options to `Get-Content` and `Set-Content`.

Any PowerShell version:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path 'index.html' -Encoding UTF8) -Replace 'type=\"module\"', 'type=\"text/javascript\"' | Set-Content -Path 'index.html' -Encoding UTF8"
```

…and shortened:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GC 'index.html' -En UTF8) -Replace 'type=\"module\"','type=\"text/javascript\"'|SC 'index.html' -En UTF8"
```

PowerShell version 3+:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path 'index.html' -Encoding UTF8 -Raw).Replace('type=\"module\"', 'type=\"text/javascript\"') | Set-Content -Path 'index.html' -Encoding UTF8"
```

…and shortened:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GC 'index.html' -En UTF8 -Ra).Replace('type=\"module\"','type=\"text/javascript\"')|SC 'index.html' -En UTF8"
```